# I want to reproduce a reactionscheme with Chemfig/Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I want to reproduce the reactionscheme on page 1322 in the paper to which the following link leads (Figure 1).  [Link to the paper.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1236362/pdf/biophysj00056-0121.pdf)
I am trying this with Chemfig and I was able to reproduce the circle in the middle. But I don't know how to get the frame around the circle. Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,siunitx}
\setcompoundsep{7em}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\definearrow1{s>}{%
\ifx\@empty#1\@empty
\expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-CF](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node);%
\else
\def\curvedarrow@style{shorten <=\CF@arrow@offset,shorten >=\CF@arrow@offset,}%
\CF@expadd@tocs\curvedarrow@style\CF@arrow@current@style
\expandafter\draw\expandafter[\curvedarrow@style,-CF](\CF@arrow@start@name)..controls#1..(\CF@arrow@end@name);
\fi
}

\schemestart
F \ \arrow(ff--aa){<=>[$k_1$][$k_{-1}$]}A \arrow(--bb){s>[+(60:1)and+(120:1)]}[,1] B
\arrow(--tt){<=>[$k_{-2}$][$k_2$]}T
\arrow(@bb--@aa){s>[+(-120:1)and+(-60:1)]}[,1]
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

It would be great, if someone could help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate the scheme with `\chemmove` (Note: requires multiple compilations).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} % required for '-o' arrow tips
\setcompoundsep{7em}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\definearrow3{s>}{% define an arrow with three arguments for labels
\ifx\@empty#1\@empty
\expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-CF](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node);%
\else
\def\curvedarrow@style{shorten <=\CF@arrow@offset,shorten >=\CF@arrow@offset,}%
\CF@expadd@tocs\curvedarrow@style\CF@arrow@current@style
\expandafter\draw\expandafter[\curvedarrow@style,-CF](\CF@arrow@start@name)..controls#1..(\CF@arrow@end@name)
    node [midway,anchor=north] {#2}
    node [midway,anchor=south] {#3};
\fi
}

\schemestart
F \arrow(ff--aa){<->>[$k_1$][$k_{-1}$]}A
\arrow(--bb){s>[+(60:1)and+(120:1)][$\alpha$]}[,1] B% add label
\arrow(--tt){<->>[$k_{2}$][$k_{-2}$]}T
\arrow(@bb--@aa){s>[+(-120:1)and+(-60:1)][][$\beta$]}[,1]% add label
\schemestop

% chemmove part
\chemmove[-o]{% sets arrow tip for every \draw
\draw ([yshift=5pt]ff.north) -- +(0,2cm) -| ([xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm]aa.north);
\draw ([yshift=5pt]tt.north) -- +(0,2cm) -| ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=1cm]bb.north);
\draw ([yshift=-5pt]ff.south) -- +(0,-2cm) -| ([xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]aa.south);
\draw ([yshift=-5pt]tt.south) -- +(0,-2cm) -| ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1cm]bb.south);
}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]